# R: date format with just year and month

Tags: r, date-format

I have a dataframe with monthly data, one column containing the year and one column containing the month. I'd like to combine them into one column with Date format, going from this:

```
Year    Month     Data
2020        1       54
2020        2       58
2020        3       78
2020        4       59
```

To this:

```
   Date    Data
2020-01      54
2020-02      58
2020-03      78
2020-04      59
```

Comment: That's a period, not a date. Date is a type of value, like integers and floats, not a format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't represent a Date format in R without showing the day. If you want a character column, like in your example, you can do:

```
> x <- data.frame(Year = c(2020,2020,2020,2020), Month = c(1,2,3,4), Data = c(54,58,78,59))
> x$Month <- ifelse(nchar(x$Month == 1), paste0(0, x$Month), x$Month) # add 0 behind.
> x$Date <- paste(x$Year, x$Month, sep = '-')
> x
  Year Month Data    Date
1 2020    01   54 2020-01
2 2020    02   58 2020-02
3 2020    03   78 2020-03
4 2020    04   59 2020-04
> class(x$Date)
[1] "character"
```

If you want a Date type column you will have to add:

```
x$Date <- paste0(x$Date, '-01')
x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

x

class(x$Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest way would be to arbitrarily set a day (e.g. 01) to all your dates ? Therefore date intervals  would be preserved.

```
data<-data.frame(Year=c(2020,2020,2020,2020), Month=c(1,2,3,4),  Data=c(54,58,78,59))
data$Date<-gsub(" ","",paste(data$Year,"-",data$Month,"-","01"))
data$Date<-as.Date(data$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the date only with "%Y-%m"? If I remove the day from your piece of code, I get a Date column all with NaNs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` -

```
sprintf('%d-%02d', data$Year, data$Month)
#[1] "2020-01" "2020-02" "2020-03" "2020-04"
```